# magento related products in stock local.xml

Tags: magento

I have a related product issue, i work with the template shopper for magento

here are the blocks in my local.xml file:

```
<reference name="content">
<action method="unsetChild" ><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
</reference>
```

and:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="content.product.related" as="content_related" template="catalog/product/list/related_content.phtml"/>
```

the file related_content.phtml exist.

i want the products to show up in the view.phtml
also the upsell products are not working..

The strange part is that related product did worked when i finished the install of the template, the products are in stock and i reindexed all the products many time.

Comment: You are dealing with some Magento customization, and it's very hard to help out without knowing the full set of custom code & markup involved.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should add the code below in your view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content_related'); ?>
```